# What is the logical complexity of the Hodge conjecture?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lo.logic

The Hodge conjecture seems to me the most mysterious among the Millennium  problems
(and many others). In particular, I am not sure about  its logical complexity.  It is not difficult  to see that the conjecture is equivalent to a  $\Pi^0_2$  statement if restricted to 
varieties over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.  (Basically, it is because these varieties form  a recursive set,  and the statement sounds like "for any Hodge class there is an algebraic cycle".)  However  the  conjecture may be  true  over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ but false  in general ; if I am not mistaken, this possibility  has not being ruled out yet. 
My guess is that the Hodge conjecture  may be formulated as  a $\Pi^0_3$  statement  but, at present, not as  $\Pi^0_2$.  Is it  true?

Some remarks.    As is well known, the Hodge conjecture may    be separated into  two parts:

I. Hodge classes are absolute,

II. Absolute Hodge classes are algebraic.

The second part  is $\Pi^0_2$.  (It  follows from  results  of  Voisin, "Hodge loci and absolute Hodge classes", Compositio Mathematica, Vol. 143 Part 4, 945-958, 2007. )  So, the  logically  hard part seems to be the first one. In view of Proposition 0.5 of the Voisin's  paper, it boils down to  whether Hodge loci are defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ or not.  I have  some  ideas about how to  translate this  into $\Pi^0_3$  but nothing close to  $\Pi^0_2$.
Naturally,  if it is  true that  the Hodge conjecture   can *not*  be formulated as a $\Pi^0_2$  statement for now,  there is no way one  can actually  prove this fact. In case it is not unlikely  to be so,  I am only asking  for an expert opinion.  Also, 
if possible,  I  would appreciate a slick  and sound proof  of the "upper bound"   $\Pi^0_3$     (although  I have some ideas about it, I do not  really like them).

Comment: what are $\Pi_{2}^0$ and $\Pi_{3}^0$?

Comment: @Libli See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy